# Mercurial .hgignore Negative Lookahead

Tags: regex, mercurial, tortoisehg, hgignore

Using Mercurial, I need to ignore all files except for those in a certain directory called "keepers".

On the face of things, this seemed easy using Regex and Negative Lookahead; however, although I am able to verify my regex in Regex Buddy and other tools, in TortoiseHg, it doesn't work as expected.

Files:

- junk\junk.txt
- junk\text
- keepers\test\test
- keepers\test\test2\hi.txt
- keepersblah.txt

Only the two files under keepers should be not be ignored.

Here is the regex I hoped would work:

```
^(?!keepers/).+$
```

Regrettably, this causes all files to be ignored.  If I change it to:

```
^(?!keepers).+$
```

it works as you would expect.  That is it ignores any files/folders that don't start with keepers.  But I do want to ignore files that start with keepers.

Bizarrely, if I change it to this:

```
^(?!keepers/).+\..+$
```

It will properly match the folder, but it will not ignore files that are not in the keepers folder if they don't have an extension.

Any advice would be appreciated.

*removing dead ImageShack link*

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem with your first expression is that the regex is also tested against "keepers" itself.  That case can be added with an additional condition:

```
^(?!keepers(?:/|$))
```

or (less compact, but simpler to understand):

```
^(?!keepers/|keepers$)
```

Comment: I also tried `^(?!keepers\b)`, but that failed against "keepers.txt"

Comment: Brilliant!  Thank you so much, both worked perfectly.  I've been banging my head for an hour :)

Comment: In a look-ahead assertion there is no need for non-capturing groups, since it's not captured anyway: `^(?!keepers(/|$)).*`