# .hgignore not matching / with negative look-ahead

Tags: regex, mercurial, hgignore

I want to use this pattern in my `.hgignore`:

```
syntax: regexp

(?<![^/])\.(?!(idea|yarn)/)
```

i.e. match all files/directories starting with a `.` other than the `.idea/` and `.yarn/` directories.

However, when I run `hg status -n --color=no`, my `.idea` files aren't listed.

If I change that last `/` to `\b` then I get:

```
.idea/blade.xml
.idea/codeStyleSettings.xml
.idea/codeStyles/Project.xml
.idea/codeStyles/codeStyleConfig.xml
.idea/copyright/profiles_settings.xml
```

`\b` is probably close enough to what I want, but I can't understand why it won't work with `.` when the status list clearly shows files with `.idea/`.

Regex101 also shows that it should work.

Match (note the "x"):

[image]

Doesn't match (as intended, because it's negated):

[image]

Comment: I'm only here because of the regex tag, and don't really know anything about hgignore, but it sounds like it could be related to the limitation described at the bottom of this page? https://wiki.mercurial-scm.org/.hgignore

Comment: I don't know what that means, "attempting to use an inverted regex match will fail when combined with other patterns". Does that mean they decided against adding inverted rules (i.e. add these files back after excluding them), or that negative look-aheads don't work?

Comment: Maybe this could be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2247110/4994744